# Having trouble creating a function that returns a vector of 5 random numbers from a pool of 20 numbers in R

Tags: r, random

Total noob here guys, I was asked to do this for a class I am taking and I'm having some trouble as my sample always pulls the same 5 numbers. I'd appreciate any tips that can steer me in the right direction. So far I have this inside the function brackets:

```r
num <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
  
rn = sample(num, 5, replace=T)
```

This will produce a vector of 5 integers, however, it is always the same 5. How can I fix this so it is always 5 different random numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I am running your code, it is not the same:

```
> num <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
> rn = sample(num, 5, replace=T)
> rn
[1] 11 18  2 18 20
> num <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
> rn = sample(num, 5, replace=T)
> rn
[1]  2  8 20  3 17
> num <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
> rn = sample(num, 5, replace=T)
> rn
[1] 13 14  7 20 14
```

If you used `set.seed()` than it will be the same:

```
> num <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
> set.seed(1)
> rn = sample(num, 5, replace=T)
> rn
[1]  4  7  1  2 11
> num <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
> set.seed(1)
> rn = sample(num, 5, replace=T)
> rn
[1]  4  7  1  2 11
```